# Саморазвитее агента в искуственной среде

Tags: нейронные-сети

Изучая нейронные сети, сделал простую сеть с обратным распространением ошибки

И тут задался вопросом, возможно ли как-то сделать сеть для агента, который сам бы обучился (без генетических алгоритмов, или в раках первой популяции)

Допустим, есть среда обитания агента, сам агент (один), частицы еды и яда
Обитая в этом мире, агент должен обучиться поедать еду и избегать яда

Ещё, хотел узнать как придать движениям агента естественности, ибо из моих наблюдений выяснил, что при отсутствии еды даже обученный агент начинает бегать по кругу (живой организм так не делает)

Прошу просто примерное описание алгоритма на словах и пинок в дальнейшем направлении, про что читать, что изучать и т.п.

Или готовую реализацию на языке с си-образным синтаксисом, если таковая имеется

Comment: Какое отношение ваш вопрос имеет к языкам программирования javascript, C++, C# и C?

Comment: Это языки, примеры реализаций на которых предпочтительны для меня

Comment: Это совершенно неправильно ставить такие метки к вашему вопросу, так как вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к самим языкам программирования. Вы могли бы просто в тексте своего вопроса указать, что если алгоритм приводится в виде уже готовой реализации на языке программирования, то для вас предпочтительны указанные языки.

Comment: Не знал. Отредактировал тему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Агент будет обучаться сам именно благодаря изменению значений (коэфициентов в синопсах). А это генетический алгоритм.

Можно сделать так, что агент будет один, не будет умирать, а будет настраивать связи узлов сети, находясь в первой популяции.

Правила игры, пусть такие:

1. Агент находится в игровой бесконечной сетке.
2. В ячейках могут быть - ничего (+0 к энергии), еда (+5 к энергии) и яд (-5 к энергии).
3. За каждый ход тратится одно очко энергии. За стояние на месте +1 добавляется.
4. Цель - максимальная длина путешествия через 10 ходов.

Агент знает оставшееся количество энергии и видит область 5*5 клеток - имеет 1+25 входных синопсов на первом уровне, которые отражают текущую способность перемещаться (-5, +бесконечность) и значения полезности ячеек (+5, +0, -5).

Пусть в сети три уровня: 26, 10, 1. Узлы следующего уровня связаны со всеми узлами предыдущего, связи между узлами разной силы, с разными коэффициентами умножения. 260 + 10 = 270 связей или 270 коэффициентов. На выходе последнего уровня должно получится число.

Если его целая часть 1 - идти влево, 2 - вверх, 3 - вправо, 4 - вниз, всё что меньше 1 или больше 4 - стоять на месте.

Сначала коэффициенты выбираются случайным образом. Делается пробное путешествие. Потом один из коэффициентов (следующий по порядку) меняется на случайную величину -0.1 до +0.1 и делается второе путешествие. Если длина путешествия увеличилась, то мутация применяется, иначе откатывается.

Оставить агента на пару миллионов итераций. Он научиться тому, что синопсам ближних клеток нужно отдавать больший приоритет при распознавании яда. Что нужно стремиться к еде. И так далее. Агент останется одним, просто будет умнее.

И визуализировать процесс скитаний агента.

Update
Добавлил выше про 26-й синопс - количество оставшейся энергии у агента.

Ответ на вопрос про длину пути.

Про длину пути. Каждый ход агент может выбрать одно из пяти действий. И сдвинуться с места или остаться стоять. И пусть так 10 ходов за раунд. Через 10 ходов вычисляется, как далеко от первоначальной позиции раунда ушел агент. Если он ходил вперёд-назад, то не ушел никуда. Если шел только вперёд, не сворачивая на обеды и ужины, то устал и остановился - прошел мало. Если продумывал путь правильно - то ушел далеко. Агент должен стремиться продумывать путь правильно в любой ситуации. Поэтому максимизируемая величина - длина пути за последние 10 ходов - неплохой выбор.

Comment: Немного не понял про дину путешествия, можно подробней?

Comment: А ещё, только что натолкнулся о способе обучения с подкреплением, пока понятия не имею, что он из себя представляет. Что можете сказать на счет этого метода?

Comment: Возможно это и называется обучение с подкреплением. Про длину пути - для обучения сети нужно же максимизировать или минимизировать некую величину. Если величина одна - то её и используем как критерий успешности обучения. Если величин несколько, то к ним применяются эвристики (коэффициенты), величины умножаются на эвристики, складываются - получается одно число, которое служит обобщённым критерием успешности обучения..

Comment: Это самый лучший алгоритм из всех альтернатив для обучения агентов?

Comment: Нет. Обучение без учителя. Алгоритм долгий, время окончания обучения неизвестно. Даже если оставить обучаться агента на сутки, возможно не обучится достаточно хорошо. Тогда нужно будет: найти ошибку в реализации, добавить проверок перед принятием новой мутации, уменьшить шаг изменения значения коэффициентов или увеличить количество синопсов/слоёв. Можете сделать обучение с учителем - заранее просчитать 5-10 ситуаций и натаскивать агента на них, обучаться будет быстрее. Но агент может переобучиться, натаскается и не сможет эффективно действовать в незнакомой ситуации.

Comment: А если все, что я могу сказать агенту, это то, что еду есть - хорошо, а яд - плохо? Например, если я захочу собрать физическую реализацию агента (робота). Как посоветуете построить алгоритм в такой ситуации?

Comment: Если правила поведения заранее известны. То логику работы можно задать прямыми условиями: `Если (...), то {...}, иначе {...}` - ненаглядно, но быстро.  Также использовал конечный автомат для парсера и сетевого протокола - более няглядный способ представления сложной логики. Конечный автомат легко расширять в отличии от дерева условий. Работа автомата в Вашем случае будет простой: Для входных данных "Состояние голода" + "Наличие еды" - действие "Есть еду". Для входных данных "Наличие яда" - действие "Искать дальше".